# Prevent overlapping values on CIDR column in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, exclusion-constraint

Is there a constraint or some other PostgreSQL feature that prevents CIDR columns from having values that overlap?

For example:

`192.168.1.0/24` and `192.168.1.1/32`

These could not exist together because `192.168.1.1/32` is contained in the `192.168.1.0/24` subnet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, that is easily done with an exclusion constraint.

```
CREATE TABLE networks (
   id integer GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
   net cidr NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE networks ADD EXCLUDE USING gist (net inet_ops WITH &&);

INSERT INTO networks (net) VALUES ('192.168.1.0/24');
INSERT 0 1

INSERT INTO networks (net) VALUES ('192.168.1.1/32');
ERROR:  conflicting key value violates exclusion constraint "networks_net_excl"
DETAIL:  Key (net)=(192.168.1.1) conflicts with existing key (net)=(192.168.1.0/24).
```

The exclusion constraint will cause an error whenever you try to insert two rows where the values for `net` overlap (`&&` is the "overlaps" operator).

Comment: Is it possible to limit the constraint based on the value of another field? E.g. I would like to validate that CIDRs do not overlap for a specific VLAN but they can overlap between different vlans. Thank you

Comment: @mhristache Sure, just add the other column to the exclusion constraint. You may need the `btree_gist` extension to use `=` in an exclusion constraint.

Comment: it'd be amazing if you could explain what is going on here.

Comment: @Rami I have added an explanation.